# Using determinant of two matrices to find the determinant of a third

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Let me start off by saying that I realise that I need to apply the following theorems:

1. If $B$ is a matrix that results when a single row or single column of $A$ is multiplied by a scalar $k$, then $\begin{vmatrix}B\end{vmatrix}=k\begin{vmatrix}A\end{vmatrix}$.
2. If $B$ is a matrix that results when two rows or two columns of $A$ are interchanged, then $\begin{vmatrix}B\end{vmatrix}=-\begin{vmatrix}A\end{vmatrix}$.
3. If $B$ is a matrix that results when a multiple of one row of $A$ is added to another row or when a multiple of one column is added to another column, then $\begin{vmatrix}B\end{vmatrix}=\begin{vmatrix}A\end{vmatrix}$.

I am just unable to translate them into application. I can see similarities between the matrices in my problem, but I am not quite sure how to actually solve it

The problem is as follows:

$$Given~~\begin{vmatrix}
a & 1 & d \\
b & 2 & e \\
c & 3 & f \\
\end{vmatrix} = 11,
\begin{vmatrix}
a & 1 & d \\
b & 1 & e \\
c & 1 & f \\
\end{vmatrix} = 7\\
Find
\begin{vmatrix}
a & 3 & d \\
b & 2 & e \\
c & 3 & f \\
\end{vmatrix}
$$

I have tried building a system of linear equations, namely:

$$c_1 * u + c_2 * v + c_3 * w = |M|$$ where $c_1$, $c_2$ and $c_3$ are the entries down the second column, and $u, v$ and $w$ are substitutes for the determinants of the matrix of minors, and $|M|$ is the determinant of the matrix. I did it regardless of the fact that I knew I would land up with 3 equations in 4 unknowns, because I thought I could do some magic with ratios of $u:v:w$, but that is not the case.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you mean to have $(3,2,1)^T$ for the middle column after the word Find?

Comment: @copper.hat No. This is as per the question.

Comment: @copper.hat It should be noted, that there is a 4th matrix as per the question, which has the middle column of $(3, 5, 7)^T$, which is trivial to solve, as per your answer in the other question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is under determined.

If you choose $c=3,d=2,e=1$,
$a={10 f + 20 \over f^2 }$, $b={10 \over f^2}$, the determinants of
the first two matrices are $11,7$ as expected, and the determinant
of the last matrix is $17-{20 \over f}$.